# How do I get statistics for the VsCode extension? like downloads&uninstalls

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to use reports to analyze the usage of the extension. I can report some info in the extension code, but the downloads, uninstalls, star ratings and other information cannot be obtained. Is there any way to get these information? Like OpenAPI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get some statistics via `vsce show` that wouldn't be too hard to parse.

```
> vsce help
Commands:
  [...]
  show [options] <extensionid>         Show extension metadata
```

Here's an example of the output for the C# extension:

```
> vsce show ms-vscode.csharp
C#
Microsoft | ↓ 6,218,092 installs | ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ •  (188)

C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp).

Recent versions:
  1.21.9  December 16, 2019
  1.21.8  November 22, 2019
  1.21.7  November 11, 2019
  1.21.6  November 5, 2019
  1.21.5  October 15, 2019
  1.21.4  October 3, 2019

Categories:
  Programming Languages, Snippets, Linters, Debuggers

Tags:
  .NET, .NET Core, ASP.NET, aspnetcorerazor, C#, csharp, debuggers, dotnet, json, keybindings, multi-root ready, snippet

More info:
  Unique identifier:  ms-vscode.csharp
  Version:            1.21.9
  Last updated:       December 16, 2019, 6:56:01 PM
  Publisher:          Microsoft
  Published at:       February 26, 2016

Statistics:
  install          6218092.00
  averagerating    3.81
  ratingcount      188.00
  trendingdaily    0.01
  trendingmonthly  20.25
  trendingweekly   2.19
  updateCount      19399015.00
  weightedRating   3.84
```

You could possibly also use the REST API [that `vsce` seems to use under the hood for this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-vsce/blob/6e5c2d5488a9283614534f4e6655969161daa977/src/util.ts) directly. There's also a somewhat related reddit discussion [here](https://old.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/am1k1t/is_there_an_api_for_getting_list_of_all/).

Comment: Any idea what the `trendingweekly` stat means? Is this number of weekly users?

Comment: Not sure what it is, but number of users doesn't really seem plausible if you compare daily / weekly / monthly in the example I gave.